# Asp.net AjaxControlToolkit tries to load the wrong version?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Well 4 weeks ago we published a new version in our web application, before the update we where using "4.1.50731.0" of AjaxControlToolkit and now we are using "4.1.60623.0", a few times a day we get the following error

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.50731.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies.

The url that gives this error is

> StartForm.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.50731.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e....

It's difference Client IP addresses that get this problem so its more than one client..

I have searched all files in the application for the "4.1.5" and did not get any hits.

My first guess that some pages where Cashed but well now after 4 weeks that doesn't seem likely any more.

Does any one have a idea what is happening here?

Comment: Can you Check if there are any controls on StartForm.aspx that use old version of ATK?

Comment: @rt2800 How would that look? if i look at the "<%@ REGISTER" tag then there is no version defined, and as i said i have searched for 4.1.5 but got no match.